# Pseudocode for coin-flipping game

Tags: ruby, pseudocode, flowchart

I'm supposed to write pseudocode for a program which will randomly generate a result of either heads or tails.

After that I need to create a flowchart for this program to allow a user to choose between a single flip, or best of three.

I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code is words written that may or may not eventually run but describes the problem that you are trying to solve as though it does.

Here is an example of pseudo-code given the problem:

```
flip_coin
output_result_of_coin_flip
```

And truly, we can make this be actual code that will run.

The flow chart is a little bit more complicated, in that you have choices of what the flow chart should look like, is it UML compliant, etc?

Regardless, it should communicate the flow through your program to result in what you need it to do.

An example of a flow-chart is such:

[image: Courtesy of Wikipedia]

Read more at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart)

Comment: Okay thanks, I get the pseudocode thing but I still have no idea what to write for the flow chart because I don't know what steps I'm supposed to use for best of 3. :P

Comment: @Alice, do you know what "best of three" is, in a real-life coin toss? Flip a coin twice, and either you have a winner, or you flip a third time, and take the winner of that toss.